# Typescript How To Return Class Function Reference From Nested Object Getter

Tags: angular, typescript, getter, es6-class

I am writing a service class which contains a collection of utility functions.  Rather than exposing all of the functions as public, the functions are concatenated into a series of public objects that are intended to provide a logical flow for accessing them.  Here's an example:

```
class MyUtilService {
    public exposedObject = {
        get prop1() {
            return this.utilFunction1;
        },
        get prop2() {
            return this.utilFunction2;
        }
    };

    private utilFunction1() {//...}
    private utilFunction2() {//...}
}
```

The issue, is that the `this` object in the getters is referring to the `exposedObject` NOT the class (as would be expected).  The goal would be to access these functions elsewhere in the application like so:

```
myUtilService.exposedObject.prop1() // Want this to execute utilFunction1
```

The other desire here is for the typing information from `utilFunction1` to be maintained when used.  I had previously used `.bind(this)` instead of getters but that prevented any typing information from being passed.  Same thing happens with `Object.defineProperty`.  Any thoughts on how I could get this to work?

**Notes:**  Using TS 2.5.x and Angular 5.x

**EDIT:**
I'm adding some additional information as the core of the issue wasn't clear in my initial post.  The main issue comes when one of the private functions uses another function from within the service.  Consider this code:

```
class MyUtilClass {
    public exposedObject = {
        prop1: this.utilFunction1
    };

    private utilFunction1() {
        this.utilFunction2();
    }
    private utilFunction2() {//...}
}

// Want this to execute utilFunction1 which executes utilFunction2
someService.exposedObject.prop1()
```

utilFunction2 is used inside of `utilFunction1` but when `myUtilClass.exposedObject.prop1()` is called, `this.utilFunction2` is not defined because the `this` context is from the caller (again, as expected).  This can be overcome with `prop1: this.utilFunction1.bind(this)` but then you lose the typing information for the function.  It's a conundrum.  That's why I went down the route of the nested getters but that has its own issues with the `this` context.

Comment: If the functions are available publicly by some property accessor, why not just make them public in the first place?

Comment: Can't you just return the function .bind(this)?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, they are **technically** public because at runtime it's just javascript and you can circumvent the TS compiler by doing myService['myPrivateFunction']().  But that's kind of circumventing the whole purpose of using TS in the first place.  In my case, I don't want to expose all of the functions publicly because separating them into a nested object provides more clarity in how to use them.  Defining the functions directly on the properties is also possible but makes the structure of the exported object hard to see.

Comment: @vicatcu `.bind(this)` is actually what I originally had, but that prevents the typing information (specifically the function argument typings) from being inherited.

Comment: @cybernet_surfer I wasn't suggesting that you circumvent TypeScript's `private` compiler hint, you misunderstand. Because the functions are publicly accessible via nested object in your proposed API (which I might add is very unorthodox and probably explains why you're having a difficult time achieving this particular approach), you should abandon the idea of the nested object and change the methods to `public`. I don't see how separating them and giving them an unintuitive calling context adds any clarity whatsoever.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts my apologies, I did misunderstand your suggestion.  You are absolutely correct that one solution is to just make all of the functions public without shunting them into an object.  The whole idea behind the exported object was that this file has ~50 functions which are used to build configuration objects (long story).  Instead of giving the user 50 functions to parse through, the object would present organized choices to get to the function they needed for their specific use case.

Comment: In that case, consider if all or many of these functions are doing a slight variation of the same thing. If so, you could replace them with a single generic call, or create a higher-order function returns each of the 50 functions based on the arguments to the call so you have less typing to do. Either way, this would add a lot more structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, here's how I ended up solving this.  Using the same example as before:

```
let _otherService: OtherService;

export class MyUtilClass {

    constructor(private otherService: OtherService) {
        _otherService = otherService;
    }

    public exposedObject = {
        prop1: utilFunction1
    };
}

function utilFunction1() {
    utilFunction2();
}
function utilFunction2() {
    _otherService.doSomething();
}
```

I ended up defining the utility functions **outside** of the main class.  Then there were no longer issues with `this`.  The functions could use one another, and I could even expose injected services via the constructor for them to reference (possible as the service is instantiated before any of these functions would be available).  And the typing information is also inherited through the exposedObject.  Thank you all for the suggestions!

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you, considering what you are trying to achieve.

```
class MyUtilService {
    public exposedObject = {
        prop1:this.prop1,
        prop2:this.prop2
    }
    private get prop1(){
        return this.utilFunction1();
    }
    private get prop2() {
        return this.utilFunction2();
    }

    private utilFunction1() {}
    private utilFunction2() {}
}

let utilityservice = new MyUtilService();
utilityservice.exposedObject.prop2;
```

Comment: Does TypeScript can prevent user from direct calling private method? `utilityservice.utilFunction1()`

Comment: Yes, typescript can implement all four principles of OOP.

Comment: Just try `utilityservice.utilFunction1()` In the dev mode server logs Error and in the browser i see that the method is really called - see the result in browser console.

Comment: Thanks @ioedeveloper! It definitely achieves what I was looking for.  It's slightly more verbose than I wish might have been possible, but it's really nice having a way to get the argument typings for those functions.  Thank you so much, really appreciate it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I didn't test this solution out as much as I need to before claiming it's success. Upon further investigation this doesn't quite get me to where I need to be.  Doing this is not decidedly different than assigning the private functions directly to the property.  I also realized I needed to add some clarity to my original question.  I'll put it in an edit.

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript is realy JavaScript under the hood. Your class is converted to javascript function before it is executed.
for example when you define funtion with get or set key word you don't use ():

```
o = {
  get number() {return 5;},
  set number(i) {this.myNumber = i;}
}
result = o.number;
o.number = 10;
```

Every object `{}` has it's own context `this`

I even didn't believe that what you expect is possible. I played a bit with your class. I was able to pass the outter contex to inner object, but privet methods are still available as public. It seem's that this is true for all TypeScript classes, same as for js, all members are public. I'm new to TypeScript and just wanted to show how much prototype (TS and JS) differs from clasic OOP

```
class MyUtilService {
  public exposedObject: Object;
  constructor() {

    class ExposedObject {
      constructor(private parent: MyUtilService) {}
      get prop1() {
          console.log(this);
          return this.parent.utilFunction1();
      }
      get prop2() {
          return;
      }
    }
    this.exposedObject = new ExposedObject(this);
  }


  private utilFunction1() { return 'uf'; }
  private utilFunction2() {}
}

const u = new MyUtilService();
const value = u.exposedObject.prop1;
console.log(value);
console.log(u.utilFunction1());
```